# como puedo sumar en una query find de mongodb utilizando $expr, actualmente me da error

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo errores al implementar el $expr en mi query, quiero utilizar el $expr porque necesito sumar unos atributos del objeto.

Query sin $expr que me funciona pero no suma:

```
> Pedido.find({
>                 "posicionesPedido.producto": busqueda,
>                 fecha: { $gte: new Date(fechadesde) },
>                 fecha: { $lte: new Date(fechahasta) }
>             })
>             .exec((err, pedidos) => {
> 
>                 if (err) {
>                     reject('Error al cargar', err);
>                 } else {
>                     resolve(pedidos);
>                 }
>             });
```

Me da como resultado:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "pedidos": [
        {
            "_id": "5c6c3cbbdd632535d4834b50",
            "fecha": "1991-06-23T00:00:00.000Z",
            "usuario": "5c30fd5890bbd24a1c46c7ee",
            "posicionesPedidos": [
                {
                    "_id": "5c6c3cbbdd632535d4834b52",
                    "id": 1,
                    "producto": "5c697b22336d65336cad9032",
                    "descripcion": "23",
                    "precio": 22,
                    "iva": 22
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c6c3cbbdd632535d4834b51",
                    "id": 2,
                    "producto": "5c6982708e2ed61550d477a1",
                    "descripcion": "22",
                    "precio": null,
                    "iva": 22
                }
            ],
            "id": 48,
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c6c3d8fbec3ab457cf5bdf7",
            "fecha": "1991-06-23T00:00:00.000Z",
            "usuario": "5c30fd5890bbd24a1c46c7ee",
            "posicionesPedidos": [
                {
                    "_id": "5c6c3d8fbec3ab457cf5bdf9",
                    "id": 1,
                    "producto": "5c697b22336d65336cad9032",
                    "descripcion": "22",
                    "precio": 22,
                    "iva": null
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5c6c3d8fbec3ab457cf5bdf8",


    "id": 2,
                "producto": "5c6984c5170588174c1b1e80",
                "descripcion": "22",
                "precio": null,
                "iva": 22
            }
        ],
        "id": 49,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5c6c408dbec3ab457cf5bdfb",
        "fecha": "2019-02-19T00:00:00.000Z",
        "usuario": "5c30fd5890bbd24a1c46c7ee",
        "posicionesPedidos": [
            {
                "_id": "5c6c408dbec3ab457cf5bdfd",
                "id": 1,
                "producto": "5c697b22336d65336cad9032",
                "descripcion": "ESTO ES ASI",
                "precio": 22,
                "iva": null
            },
            {
                "_id": "5c6c408dbec3ab457cf5bdfc",
                "id": 2,
                "producto": "5c6982708e2ed61550d477a1",
                "descripcion": "ESTO ES ASI",
                "precio": null,
                "iva": 22
            }
        ],
        "id": 50,
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

}

Necesito sumar el IVA y el Precio de todas las posiciones.

Lo que he intentado con el EXPR:

```
Pedido.find({
        $expr: { 
            $eq: [ "$posicionesPedido.producto" , busqueda ],
            $gte: ["$fecha" , new Date(fechadesde)],
            $lte: ["$fecha" , new Date(fechadesde)],
            $cond: {
                { $sum: "$precio", sum_precio },
                { $sum: "$iva", sum_iva }
              }
        }
    })
    .exec((err, pedidos) => {

        if (err) {
            reject('Error al cargar', err);
        } else {
            resolve(pedidos);
        }
    });
```

pero no va ni el sum ni el find e intentado de mil maneras mas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el 'find' no sabría hacerlo pero si con ['aggregate'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/).

Te muestro una posible solución para tu caso:

```
Pedido.aggregate([
        {
            "$unwind": '$posicionesPedidos' //Esto es para descomponer el Array en documentos.
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                _id: "$_id", //Agrupamos por cada _id (suponiendo que es única)
                "totalPrice": {"$sum": "$posicionesPedidos.precio"}, //Sumamos todos los precios de cada _id
                "totalIVA": {"$sum": "$posicionesPedidos.iva"}, //Sumamos todos los IVAs de cada _id
                "count": {"$sum": 1} //Contador del numero de elementos calculados por cada _id
            }
        }
    ])
```

Para más info, mírate esta documentación que te ayudará a enterdelo mejor [$group (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Ya nos informas.

Un saludo